# How to implement "login as" admin function with `stormpath-flask`

Tags: python, flask, stormpath

I'm implementing a "login as" feature for our admin dashboard.

Basically I'd love to allow our admins to see and use the website as if she has logged in as a specific customer. For example, if Trish rang us up and asked a question, our admin should be able to login as Trish and see exactly what Trish is seeing.

And here is the code I've written assuming we have a valid `email`:

```
from app import stormpath_manager
from flask.ext.stormpath import login_user
... 
main_cloud_directory = stormpath_manager.client.directories.search({
    'name': 'Directory Name'})[0]
accounts = main_cloud_directory.accounts.search({'email': email})
if accounts.size == 1:
    account = accounts[0]
    login_user(account, remember=False)
    return redirect('/settings')
else:
    abort(404)
```

When I run the code, I got `AttributeError: Account has no attribute 'is_active'` back.

To set the context for this:

1. I understand that `login_user` is expecting to see an `User` object which extends `stormpath.resource.Account` whereas the `account` object we received have no `is_active` defined.
2. I have code in other part of the app working just fine if I send `login_user` the `User` object returned by `stormpath_account = StormpathUser.create(...)`  method.
3. I am also aware that I am mixing the `stormpath-flask` with the raw `stormpath-python-sdk` and I guess that I really should be using `stormpath-flask` methods.
4. I can see that with `Account.email`, I can create a `User` object using `User.from_login` but this won't work because we don't store password on our end.

I'm wondering are there any way I can take an `Account` returned by the `search` method and turn it into a `User`? What would you do to make this working?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of this library, so wanted to hop in here =)

The answer is yes: you can indeed transform a normal `Account` object into a valid Flask-Stormpath `User` object. Here's how:

```
from flask.ext.stormpath import login_user
from flask.ext.stormpath.models import User

from app import stormpath_manager


# ...


main_cloud_directory = stormpath_manager.client.directories.search({
    'name': 'Directory Name'
})[0]
accounts = main_cloud_directory.accounts.search({'email': email})

if accounts.size == 1:
    account = accounts[0]
    account.__class__ = User
    login_user(account, remember=False)

    return redirect('/settings')
else:
    abort(404)
```

The important bit is the `account.__class__ = User`. This uses some meta magic to convert the class into a `User` object =) This is what I do behind the scenes in the library as well, for instance: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask/blob/4185f2f41574156870ce1aa990d34e4ad84357be/flask_stormpath/models.py#L125-L126

Hope that helps!

Comment: Aha! That's using Python to its finest. Kudos, sir!